# Build Android (Java/Kotlin) application using CMake

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, kotlin, cmake

I am able to build Java/Kotlin android application using android studio.

I am trying to build android application using CMake but not able to find any source documentation on it.

Is there a way to build Android application written in Java or Kotlin using CMake ?

Comment: I usually don't like saying "just don't", but, in this case, i swear it's better to just stick with Gradle as its scripting capabilities fit perfectly within the Android ecosystem and the dependency management is completely fine with the android-gradle-plugin, provided by Google itself.

Comment: as per my knowledge, CMake used in Android to communicate with C/C++ libraries but can we able to create android application using CMake ? Is it possible ?